# How to check if registration number includes string - c# console app

Tags: c#, string, console-application

This is my homework and i've been trying to resolve it but i just can't figure it out.

I need to create records of students that are involved into some class and i need to order them by registration number, name, etc...

Everything works fine, but i do not know, how to check if the registration number includes *E* in it.

This is what i need to type in:

Name : Mark

Last Name : Markson

Registration Number : **E111111**

Date of Birth: 1990

**My code**

```
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter reg number:");
                    newStudent.regNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                } while (newStudent.regNumber.Length != 8 && newStudent.regNumber[0] == 'E');
```

**My problem**

If i type in reg number : B111111, it says user added, instead of "wrong reg number"

Please help. Where did i go wrong?

**Important**

I can use only basic functions from .net library and use of complex functions like - sorting, searching charaters and things like that is strictly forbidden.

Comment: The do-while construction is not correct, please look [here (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/370s1zax.aspx).

Comment: @M.Mimpen yeah i knowm i have edited my post

Comment: I have found the solution thanks to every1 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 do {
     Console.WriteLine("Enter reg. number: ");
     newStudent.regNumber = Console.ReadLine();
     if (newStudent.regNumber.Length == 7 && newStudent.regNumber[0] == 'E'){
         break;
     }
     else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("wrong reg number");
     }
 } while (true);
```

Comment: it gives the **wrong reg number** even when i write it with **E**

Comment: 7, but with **E** it's 8

Comment: In your sample code your string is only 7 long... E1234567 (8) E123456 (7)

Answer (score 1):

```
        do
        {
            Student newStudent = new Student(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter reg. number: ");
            newStudent.regNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (newStudent.regNumber.Length != 8)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Registration number should has a length of 8 characters");
            }
            else 
            {
                bool hasE = false; 
                for(int i = 0 ; i < newStudent.regNumber.Length; i++)
                {
                    if(newStudent.regNumber[i] == 'E') 
                    {
                        hasE = true;
                        break; 
                    }
                }

                if(hasE == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Registration number correct :)"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Registration number does not contain E"); 
                }
            }
        }
        while(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no while do loop in C#,
Do while loop is like that, but it will not work for you

```
    do
    {
        // your code
    } while (newStudent.regNumber.Length != 8 && newStudent.regNumber[0] == 'E');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using [StartWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baketfxw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)   function of string class.

```
while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter reg. number: ");
    newStudent.regNumber = Console.ReadLine();
    if (newStudent.regNumber.Length != 8 && newStudent.regNumber.StartWith("E"))
    {
       break;
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("wrong reg number");
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot use StartWith, it's forbidden.

Comment: May be you miss using statements.